# Android convertView

Tags: android, listview, convertview

i have used horizontal listview like this with Baseadapter.

```
private class ListViewItemClickListener implements
            AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            if (imageview != null) {
                previousImage = (ImageView) imageview
                        .findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                previousImage.setSelected(false);
                TextView previousTitle = (TextView) textview
                        .findViewById(R.id.title);
                previousTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#33D6AD"));
                previousTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 13);
            }

            selected_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            selected_image.setSelected(true);

            selected_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            selected_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#368AFF"));
            selected_text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);

            select_position = position;

            imageview = selected_image;
            textview = selected_text;

        }
    }

private static String[] dataObjects = new String[] { "그랜드 캐니언",
            "그레이트 베리어 리프", "디즈니 월드", "뉴질랜드 남섬", "케이프 타운", "암리차르의 황금사원",
            "라스베가스", "시드니", "뉴욕", "타지마할" };

private BaseAdapter mAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return dataObjects.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.listitem, null);
            }
            TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setText(dataObjects[position]);

            return convertView;
        }
    };
```

and i want to change textcolor if one item is clicked. but whenever i click one item in the listview, two item's color are changing right now. and distance between those two item is always 5. I am using convertView on the getView code. and textcolor change code is in clicklistener method. can i solve this with setTag, getTag. and if it is, how can i solve this?

Comment: Post your click listener.

Comment: Show your change color codes

Comment: You want to highlight the selected item..Am i correct??

Comment: yes i want to highlight selected item. but when i click one item, unclicked item next 5 also was changed.

Comment: Why are you using mPager.setCurrentItem(position);??

Comment: You need to put color change code in adapter

Comment: Post you adapter code

Comment: oh. sorry mPager is not related with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code in your adapter class :

```
private int selectedPos = -1;


public void setSelectedPosition(int pos){
    selectedPos = pos;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}



 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.listitem, null);
       }
       TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
       title.setText(dataObjects[position]);

        if (selectedPos == position) {
            title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#368AFF"));
            title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
        } else {
           title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

And on item click, call method to set current position:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
                adapter.setSelectedPosition(pos);
        }
```

Comment: SweetWisher, you mean i have to put your code into BaseAdapter mAdapter = new BaseAdapter(){//here?????}?

Comment: I did as you say. but this time, nothing has changed. even if i click one item, there's no change as your code.

Comment: Then you must be missing something.. this code works for me. debug n check whether if (selectedPos == position)  is fulfilled or not.. If you position is updated correctly, it will work like a charm. There must be problem with position..Did u called setSelectedPosition in item Click of listview??

Comment: everything works except selected text color change. and i of course called setSelectedPosition.

Comment: Put this line title.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#368AFF")); Better u show me ur code so that i can resolve ur issue

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41839/discussion-between-sweetwisher-and-moon-taejin)

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

```
private class ListViewItemClickListener implements
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(position);


        selected_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        selected_image.setSelected(true);

        selected_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        selected_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#368AFF"));
        selected_text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);

        select_position = position;

        imageview = selected_image;
        textview = selected_text;

        view.setTag((Integer) position);
    }
}
```

Comment: no. it still two items checked. one is my selection item and another is 5 distance item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 convertView.setOnClickListener
```

instead of

```
 onItemClick
```